# Is it possible by API to insert messages in Google Groups?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-groups, google-groups-api

I'm building tools for maintaining our Google Apps for Business account.

Is there anyway to post content into a Google Group that isn't email? Ideally from within Apps Script but i'm in no way averse to using AppEngine or other exposure to API to achieve this end.

The essential use case is to be able to extract labelled email in a users account and replicat

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google just today announced the new Google Groups Migration API that allows you to import messages into a Google Group. The messages will not be sent out to group members via email but will appear in the group archive which sounds like your end goal:

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/groups-migration/

Comment: marked as accepted answer, though i've not had time to test it since the announcement. UrlfetchApp has a 10MB limit, so any emails with larger attachments I will have to think of an alternative solution.

Comment: Plus 100mB per day limit. Will have to see how to manage that.

Comment: Also, only works for Google Apps accounts, and not for ordinary Groups mailing lists.

Answer (score 1):

The [Groups service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_groups) in Apps Script doesn't provide a way of directly posting content to a Google Group, though it has some methods for managing groups. You mentioned that you didn't want to do it via email, but if sending an email to the group programmatically (via Apps Script) would work, you can use [MailApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_mail) or the [Gmail service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_gmail).

Comment: Yes, that is my fall-back in a sense the question is more about the fundamentals of the groups API first, before looking at Apps Script implementations